# Intuition About the Infinite Monkey Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, cardinals

The infinite monkey theorem states something like:

**If a random process generates a countably infinite ordered set of characters C, then any finite ordered set of characters S of length L is almost surely an ordered subset of C**.

Since every string S of length L is almost surely going to appear arbitrarily many times in C, then isn't the sample space generated by strings of length L uncountable, creating an uncountable value of almost sure outcomes in a countable sample space C?

I understand that every finite string is a substring of countably infinitely many finite strings, and it's quite trivial that any single character is almost sure to appear. The proof where the probability of an arbitrarily chosen string not appearing approaches zero also seems clear. I understand that removing S and all characters before S in C yields a sample space C*=C\X (X representing the set from index 0 to the index at the end of S), where C* and C have the same cardinality.

My issue is when you collect all of the arbitrary strings of arbitrary length, we seem to have more outcomes as almost sure then there are outcomes available. How could it be true that uncountably many finite strings are almost surely substrings of a countable string? Isn't that a measurable space of almost sure outcomes in a sample space of measure 0?

A simpler question for intuition is how can S almost always be almost sure to appear in C\S (removing the first time it appears), if the operation is repeated arbitrarily many times?

Comment: "we seem to have more outcomes as almost sure then there are outcomes available." How so? There are uncountably many possible outcomes (i.e. infinite strings that could be the output of the random process) and only countably many finite strings that we're looking for as substrings.

Comment: Also, notice that these almost sure events can overlap, since a single infinite string has infinitely many substrings.

Comment: "Then isn't the sample space generated by strings of length L uncountable...?"  No.

Comment: For any fixed $L$, there are only *finitely* many strings of length $L$.

Comment: Edited that any string S is almost sure to appear infinitely many times

Comment: Even if we divide everything the monkey writes into blocks with length $N$ (where $N$ can be huge) and fix a given string of length $N$ (for example the third Harry Potter roman) , then the chance that the block is this string is positive , hence the probability is $1$ that it eventually appears. This can be repeated forever , hence the string must appear infinite many times.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing about the sample space is uncountable. A string of length $L$ is made from a language with $k$ different characters, i.e. simply an element of $[L]^k$. The point is that a given string always has a finite length. The space of all possible infinite-length strings is no longer countable, since we can inject it into the real numbers $abcde... \mapsto a.bcde...$.

Comment: The sample space becomes uncountable when appealing that S in [L]^k almost surely appears arbitrarily many times, although your response appeared before I had actually put that in the question.

Comment: Sure, but you can say the same thing about integers, which are countable. Any given integer $k$ appears in $10k$, $100k$, $\cdots$. Your space $[L]^k$ is finite for any given $k$ and only uncountable once you've already taken the limit $k \to \infty$. But for any finite $k$ it is countable.